# "undefined is null or not an object" in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I don't know why but IE6,IE7 show me an error "undefined is null or not an object" when I try web-site there.
Web-site:http://eco-impulse.com.ua/

jQuery code (begining of code):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var oldObjId = '';
$('.slide-nav a').bind("click", function (e) {
    $(".slide-nav a").removeClass('active-n');
    $(this).addClass('active-n');
    var ObjId = $(this).attr('id');
    ObjId = parseInt(ObjId, 10);

    if (oldObjId != ObjId) {
        if (ObjId == 2) {
            $("img.slide-img-1").animate({
                marginLeft: "-100",
            }, 500, function () {});
        } else if (ObjId != 1) {...
```

full:http://eco-impulse.com.ua/general.js

Comment: Just a shot into the dark: Jquery 1.10 is not compatible with IE6 and 7.

Comment: @reporter IE7 support is removed in jQuery 2.0. 1.x still supports it.

Comment: Have you considered just dropping support for IE6/7? There really are very few people still using them. (especially IE6, which stop getting security patches starting early next year, and should therefore be considered a major security risk)

Answer (score 0):

I didnt read all the js, but in older versions of IE the console object is undefined when the the console is not open in the browser. That is a common reason for the problem you're seeing

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: How so? This is a possible solution to OPs problem, not a note on the question it self or a request for clarification